# Using chain rule in differential equations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, calculus

I am trying to use the chain rule for a differential equation that was previously defined.

```
x'[t] == -v + zy;
D[x^2, t]
```

Mathematica claims that the answer is 0; however, x depends on t.

What would be the easiest way to tell Mathematica to apply the chain rule here?
Thanks,
Yasir

Comment: Does this do what you want? `D[x[t]^2, t]/.x'[t]->-v+zy` which returns `2*(-v + zy)*x[t]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I need! And sorry for the amateurish question.